# Regex to exclude certain error types from the log

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am relatively new to this but I need help to write a regex to exclude certain known error types from a log.

```
00:11:04 [0] 70-Error: Invalid index command: "/search.asp".
00:11:04 [0] 70-Error: Invalid index command: "/wingate-internal//boot.ini".
00:11:04 [0] 70-Error: Invalid index command: "/".
```

and exclude this:

```
04:16:46 [8] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not  allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS".
04:14:17 [7] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS".
```

I have other error types within the same log which are fine for reporting, for example:

```
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
```

In other words, I would like the regex to report on all errors except the two types mentioned above.

I tried creating this regex but it doesn't seem to work:

```
/(?:)(?:[^Error\:\ Action\ failed\ \-\ unencrypted\ communication\ is\ not\ allowed]*)(?:[^Error\:\ Invalid\ index\ command\:]*)/m
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that you want to use Regex for this? If there is nothing you want to capture in separate groups, it would be a lot easier to just check in code if the string contains the word "failed" for example.

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions.

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: apologies, i only tried to do this as i realised ive got another article with the same content and answer

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^(?!.*Error: Invalid index command)(?!.*Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                           : begining of the string
(?!                         : negative lookahead (asserts that the following is not present in the string
    .*                      : 0 or more (*) any character but newline (.)
    Error: Invalid index command   : literally
)                           : end of lookahead
(?!                         : negative lookahead (asserts that the following is not present in the string
    .*                      : 0 or more (*) any character but newline (.)
    Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed : literally
)                           : end of lookahead
```

This regex matches all lines that do not contain `Error: .........`

In use in a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my $re1 = qr/^(?!.*Error: Invalid index command)(?!.*Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed)/;

while(<DATA>) {
    print if /$re1/;
}

__DATA__
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
00:11:04 [0] 70-Error: Invalid index command: "/search.asp".
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
00:11:04 [0] 70-Error: Invalid index command: "/wingate-internal//boot.ini".
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
00:11:04 [0] 70-Error: Invalid index command: "/".
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
04:16:46 [8] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS".
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
04:14:17 [7] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS".
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
```

**Output:**

```
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
17:43:17.370 ExecuterW: 957:Error [2400] DB Matters - addDocToWorklist - doSqlCommand: Error executing SQL statement - CID ed83d1e0d
```

Comment: @O.E: That's exactly what my regex do. Did you try it? I'm asking again: what tool or programing language are you using?

Comment: @O.E: There're not any problems to use it in java.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. I am using regex101 builder, when i try your regex, i get the following message: Your regular expression does not match the subject string.**

Comment: @O.E: Sorry I've made a mistake, move `Error: ` inside the lookahead (twice), see my edit.

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't work as nothing gets highlighted within the regex101 builder ie nothing matches

Comment: @O.E:It should be right now. Take care that you have to test one line at a time.

Comment: I get this error **Your pattern contains one or more errors, please see the explanation section above.** and the above section bit message is **(?! Incomplete group structure** It highlights the 2nd **(?!.** in **(?!.*Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed**

Comment: @O.E:Add a close parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Hi, I think your regex excludes all the log lines that have the word error in it, which maybe the reason it isn't working for me. I do have other errors in the log which i need reporting on, the only errors it shouldn't report on are those that have the type **18/02/2016 04:16:46 [8] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed.** and **23/09/2016 00:11:04 [0] 70-Error: Invalid index command:**

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\[\d\]\s+\d+-(Error:\s+Action\s+failed\s+\-\s+unencrypted\s+communication\s+is\s+not\s+allowed\s+.+|Error:\s+Invalid\s+index\s+command:\s+.+)
```

This has been tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/fB6hW0/12) for multiple inputs.

A little introduction and explanation of what it is doing:

\d: means matches individual digit. For number 23, this would match 2 and 3 as separate digit but not as one digit
\d+: means match at least one digit followed by any number of multiple digits. It would read 23 as one single digit.
\s: means matching one space
\s+: match multiple space or even a tab. Some may say that we can use \t for tab but tab is concatenation of space so have used that here.
[]: means match any one of the characters present inside the square brackets
(): mean match all the expression present inside the small brackets

**Explanation:**
Your input string:

> 04:16:46 [8] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is
>   not  allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS".

```
-->`\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\[\d\]`
```

> matches  04:16:46 [8]

```
-->\s+\[\d\]\s+\d+-
```

> matches [8] 70- including the space before[8]

```
-->(Error:\s+Action\s+failed\s+\-\s+unencrypted\s+communication\s+is\s+not\s+allowed\s+.+
```

> matches till Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not
>   allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS".

Please Note in the above regex `.+` at the end means, after **allowed** and a **Space** match every thing else followed by it.
Hope this clarifies.

| stands for OR

```
-->Error:\s+Invalid\s+index\s+command:\s+.+)
```

> matches Error: Invalid index command: followed by any
>   string/number/special characters

Note: (a|b) matches expression a and b if both are present else it matches either of the expression present.

Comment: @O.E Yes, it will ignore dates, times and IP's as the reg exp written is generalized for those inputs

Comment: @O.E I thought you only wanted to exclude these two:
04:16:46 [8] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not  allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS".
04:14:17 [7] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS".
The regex only handles these two error. do you want to notify all Starting with Error keyword?

Comment: Hi Shreyas, just to add to this, the programming language i need to use this regex in in Java based

Comment: How do i include the date in: **18/02/2016** 04:16:46 [8] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS". in your regex: \d+:\d+:\d+\s+\[\d\]\s+\d+-(Error:\s+Action\s+failed\s+\-\s+unencrypted\s+communication\s+is\s+not\s+allowed\s+.+|Error:\s+Invalid\s+index\s+command:\s+.+)

Comment: i used the regex on the regex101 builder on my sample log and it seems to select those errors rather than exclude them. Any ideas?

Comment: @O.E do you want this particular date 18/02/2016 only to exclude?

Comment: I ran the regex you sent on my sample log within regex101 & it seems to highlight the error types I wanted excluded. Shouldn't the highlighted text be the errors i want included in the log, i.e instead of highlighting **04:16:46 [8] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS".** and **00:11:04 [0] 70-Error: Invalid index command: "/database.cgi?file=Forum&report=TopicIndex".** it should highlight **23:43:08 [1] 70-Error: Error renaming file G:\Autonomy\WorkSite Content1\secindex/000001/000/sec.000177.db**

Comment: So in other words, **4:16:46 [8] 70-Error: Action failed - unencrypted communication is not allowed (10.40.88.11): "ACTION=GETSTATUS"**. and **00:11:04 [0] 70-Error: Invalid index command: "/database.cgi?file=Forum&report=TopicIndex".** should not be highlighted as those are errors to be excluded. and other errors will be hightlighted